# Modelling nested XML elements in Django

Tags: xml, django, data-modeling

I am working on importing XML data into Django models. For example, I could use the following XML:

```
<family surname="Jones">
    <person name="Bob" />
</family>
```

to populate the following Django models:

```py
class Family(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Person(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, related_name="people")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

In the XML, there is the concept of 'triggers' with 'conditions'. For example:

```
<trigger>
    <condition ... />
    <action>Do something</action>
</trigger>
```

A trigger may have one condition-type element, where 'condition-type' means either a `condition` element or an element containing a group of `condition` elements (ie. `and` or `or`), which are to be read as 'if all the conditions evaluate' or 'if some of the conditions evaluate'. Each 'condition group' may in turn contain one or more condition-type elements. A more complex example follows:

```
<trigger>
    <and>
        <condition />
        <or>
            <condition />
            <condition />
            <and>
                <condition />
                <condition />
            </and>
        </or>
    </and>
    <action>Do something</action>
</trigger>
```

I can't figure out the best way to model this with Django. Ideally I'd like the `Trigger` model to link to an abstract `ConditionType` model (which can be either a `Condition` or a `ConditionGroup`), and the `ConditionGroup` model (but not the `Condition` model) to link to multiple `ConditionType` models.

I'm reasonably new to Django models. I have read the documentation with regards to model inheritance, but still can't figure out how to model something quite so complex as this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I eventually solved the problem by having the following three classes: `ConditionGroup`, `SubConditionGroup` and `Condition`. `SubConditionGroup` inherits from `ConditionGroup`. `ConditionGroup`s may be of type 'single', 'and' or 'or', where 'single' contains a `Condition` and the other two can contain multiple `SubConditionGroup`s.

So, my finished model looks something like this:

```py
class Trigger(Model):
    ...
    condition_group = ForeignKey(...)


class ConditionGroup(Model):
    type = CharField(...)  # options="and"|"or"|"single"
    condition = OneToOneField(..., null=True, blank=True)


class SubConditionGroup(ConditionGroup):
    parent = ForeignKey(ConditionGroup, ...)


class Condition(Model):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you forget about modelling the XML, and concentrate on modelling whatever the XML is supposed to model.

As to how you model this, there is little more anyone can tell you without knowing what you want to do; right now we have little more than a sequence of names from you.

You can create abstract models, by setting `abstract = True` in the `Meta` class.

As to linking a Group to several Conditions, the best way is to have `ForeignKey` on the Conditions, which links them to their containing group. In this way, each Condition will belong to no more than one Group.

Comment: The `trigger`, `condition`, `action` XML is supposed to model a logical chain of events, ie. 'if `condition` happens then we need to do `action`'. If you can suggest an alternative way to model this, then please go ahead.

Comment: So, I've just been thinking of having an abstract model `ConditionContainer` from which `Trigger` and `ConditionGroup` both inherit, and having both `Condition` and `ConditionGroup` link back to `ConditionContainer` using the `ForeignKey` field.

Unfortunately it turns out that's not possible because `ForeignKey` can't be linked to an abstract model.

Comment: @JoelCross: You could have ConditionContainer as a concrete class.

Comment: @JoelCross Have you considered eliminating condition group, and just have condition have a foreignkey to the next condition, which can be None or not as necessary?